# Laravel PackageManifest.php line 131: Undefined index: name

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I updated the composer with this command:

```
composer self-update
```

It was updated to version 2.0.4. Then when I tried to launch my Laravel project using:

```
php artisan serve
```

I got this error:

```
In PackageManifest.php line 131:

 Undefined index: name
```

I tried getting back to the old version of the composer with this:

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

The composer was downgraded to version 1.9.3, but it didn't help with the error.
Then I used this command to update the composer again:

```
composer self-update --stable
```

And still got the same error.

This is the line 131 of the PackageManifest.php file:

```
return [$this->format($package['name']) => $package['extra']['laravel'] ?? []];
```

Comment: After using `composer self-update` to update version of composer, did you tried to run again`composer update` before running `php artisan serve`?

Comment: no, should I try it now?

Comment: Yes, you should do it.

Comment: First, you should check again version after using `composer self-update`. Then, you try  `composer update`. Finally, you run `php artisan serve`

Comment: That's what I was missing! It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First, you should check again version after using `composer self-update`. Then, you try `composer update`. Finally, you run `php artisan serve`.

Answer (score 24):

The issue is one of the Laravel default vendor packages has a small bug.

The solution to fix this is the following:

```
rm -rf composer.lock
rm -rf vendor
composer install
```

This will update the composer packages to the latest versions for your current version of laravel and this should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 13):

This was actually fixed in Laravel already, so please make sure you update Laravel to at least 6.18.7+ or 7.6.0+ or 8.0+

FYI, if you remove composer local file, it will update all your dependencies, so it's not a good idea.

By running the command `composer update laravel/framework` should hopefully fix the issue and not cause any other problems. If you can not update Laravel then you better off downgrade to Composer 1 using `composer self-update --1`.

If you are using `illuminate/foundation` instead of `laravel/framework`, then make sure you `composer update illuminate/foundation` instead.

Comment: this helped me : downgrade to Composer 1 using composer self-update --1

Comment: Downgrading composer to version 1 (which same version on production server) was the best solution. The whole purpose of having of local environment is to be as similar to production as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

add code in Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php about to line 129:

```
    ...
    $ignoreAll = in_array('*', $ignore = $this->packagesToIgnore());
    // ------------------:::::::::FIX::::::::::------------
    if (isset($packages['packages'])){
        $packages = $packages['packages'];
    }
    // ---------------------------ENDFIX-------------------
    $this->write(collect($packages)->mapWithKeys(function ($package) {
    ...
```

Comment: Of course. But sometimes we need to ignore rules, becouse the life is more complicated then rules. This is one of these cases. this fix make composer workable to update the saint vendor folder too. You can publish your decision better than this.

Comment: then one day you are left scratching your head because you did something stupid and ignored the rules.  The solution is already posted here from @advertmanagerpro.com

Comment: He offers an ax, and I offer a scalpel, both tools solve the problem, the choice is up to the user

Comment: This worked for me, although my edit was done on line 121, not 129

Comment: I agree with @Snapey, you should never change code directly inside the vendor folder. As you will very likely loose it as soon as you do a composer update or try to install a new composer package. Plus most people have the vendor folder in the .gitignore file so the vendor folder will never get saved to backup repositories like github or similar. It is bad practice to make changes inside the vendor folder.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:

Open
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php

then search code :

```
$packages = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
```

insert

```
$packages = $installed['packages'] ?? $installed;
```

Option 2 :

run command

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 2):

this helped me :

downgrade to Composer 1 using

```
composer self-update --1
```