# PackageManifest.php line 131 Undefined index:name after trying to install a package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I was working with laravel 6 version. I tried to install mpdf package to create a "pdf download" option. I used `composer require carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf` command. It didn't install the package and gave me this message

> PackageManifest.php line 131 Undefined index:name

I had the same experience with installation of dompdf.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel PackageManifest.php line 131: Undefined index: name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620849/laravel-packagemanifest-php-line-131-undefined-index-name)

Comment: @Finwe that post did not answer my question. Do you have any suggestions? I am on Laravel v8.9 and composer 2.0.13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177995/laravel-packagemanifest-php-undefined-index-name

Answer (score 8):

**this page**

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php
this line comment :

```
$packages = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
```

Add two lines:

```
$installed = json_decode($this->files->get($path), true);
$packages = $installed['packages'] ?? $installed;
```